# Does Upstart emit hooks for SysV jobs?

Tags: upstart

I want to make an Upstart job start immediately before a System V job (`/etc/rc0.d/S40umountfs`). I've tried specifying:

```
start on starting umountfs
```

but Upstart doesn't recognize the name of the script:

```
$ initctl check-config 
collapsefs
  start on: unknown job umountfs
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SysV init scripts are run by the `rc` job (`/etc/init/rc.conf`) which just runs `/etc/init.d/rc $RUNLEVEL`.

So there's only an upstart event for the whole runlevel, but not for single init scripts.

You can create an event using `initctl emit umountfs`.

See [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practices](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) for some tips on using Upstart.