# How can I run this script on startup, restart, and shutdown?

Tags: bash, upstart

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

I've written a script, that synchronises a directory in `~` with a directory on `/dev/sda4`, using Unison. Before, I had this script running every five minutes with no problems, using crontab. Right now, I want to execute this script at startup, restart and shutdown only.

This is what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
unison -perms 0 -batch "/mnt/Data/Syncfolder/" "/home/myname/Syncfolder/"
```

I'd like the script to be run with mechanisms like Upstart, if possible. So I'd be happiest with a properly configured `*.conf` file in `/etc/init`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and asking here, I managed to get it working:

Before doing the following, make sure that you aren't using `unison-gtk` (the Unison GUI) as well. I've had a situation in which `unison` and `unison-gtk` conflicted. Remove `unison-gtk` via `sudo apt-get remove unison-gtk`, and disable Unison's old config files by renaming the containing folder: `mv .unison .unison.old`

When you've done that, it's time to move on.

First I ran the script as a superuser. I did that because Unison needs to be run once when you create a new script, to make some logging files. The Upstart-scripts are probably run as root, so it's best to do that too when you run the script for the first time:

`sudo su`

`unison -perms 0 -batch "/home/MyName/Syncfolder" "/mnt/Data/Syncfolder" >> /var/log/unison.log`

`exit`

Then, I ran: `sudo gedit /etc/init/unison.conf`. I pasted the following, and saved the file:

```
description "My File Sync"
author "My Name"
env HOME=/home/MyName
start on runlevel [0123456]

pre-start script
    echo "Starts syncscript"
end script

post-stop script
    echo "Ends syncscript"
end script

exec unison -perms 0 -batch "/home/MyName/Syncfolder" "/mnt/Data/Syncfolder" >> /var/log/unison.log
```

Restart and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you forget SysV if possible and use `/etc/init` new style scripts. Something like this (put it in `/etc/init/unison.conf` for example):

```
start on (runlevel [06] or local-filesystems)
task
# If it needs to run other than root (you need Upstart 1.4, otherwise use "su" on exec line
setuid <username>

script
  # You can place your entire script here, no need for separate script
  exec unison -perms 0 -batch "/mnt/Data/Syncfolder/" "/home/myname/Syncfolder/"
end script
```

Comment: This looks cool, how can I make this script get executed on multiple runlevels?

Comment: `start on (runlevel[06] ..."` says it is started on runlevel 0 and 6 (shutdown and reboot) or when `local-filesystems` event is emitted (startup). In this specific case you don't need more runlevels, but generally, just use runlevel numbers inside `[]`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I got a wrong stanza error at startup. I commented out the `setuid` part, and replaced the `runlevel [06] or local-filesystems)` with `runlevel [016]`. The error disappeared, I'll tell you soon whether or not the script was executed both at startup and shutdown.

Comment: If you don't have local-filesystems event, you might want to use `runlevel [0123456]` to cover boot up completely, unless you know you're only booting to single-user (runlevel 1).

Comment: Tuminoid, it still doesn't work. Would you be so kind to take another look at it? I myself have been looking around too. On upstart.ubuntu.com, I found that a .conf file should have either a `script` or an `exec` stanza, so I guess that that's at least one of the reasons why it doesn't work yet.

Comment: `exec` and `script` on top-level are overriding each other, yes, but `exec` here is within the `script` and exec here means standard `exec` command. Can you give further information what exactly doesn't work, or what happens? Logs...

Comment: I've been fiddling a lot with it yesterday, it looks like it works now. I'll be testing some more and post the script here as soon as it works.

Comment: Yes, it works now. The script is run on both startup and shutdown. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

test your script... if it works do you can do your crontab like this

```
@reboot sh /usr/local/bin/s4lj.bash
```

this way it will work at start up

info:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/crontab.1.html
http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/cron.shtml
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

Comment: Thanks, but that makes it only work on startup. I want it to be ran at shutdown and reboot too.

Answer (score 0):

The old way (using `/etc/init.d`, and links to it from `/etc/rc?.d/[SK]*`) is handled by `/etc/init.d/rc`. Read that script carefully, and find out which one of its rules is keeping you from from being executed. Um, maybe I want to restate that.

[Does Upstart emit hooks for SysV jobs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47649/does-upstart-emit-hooks-for-sysv-jobs) has a good Upstart answer.